# jquery how to sort array by text input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to sort the data in the array according to user input.
Follow the example below. What do I have to do?

array data sample

```
0: Array
   0: "1"
   1: "text1"
   2: "text2"
   3: "text3"
1: Array
   0: "2"
   1: "text1"
   2: "text2"
   3: "text3"
2: Array
   0: "3"
   1: "text1"
   2: "text2"
   3: "text3"
```

text input: 3, 1, 2

result

```
0: Array
   0: "3"
   1: "text1"
   2: "text2"
   3: "text3"
1: Array
   0: "1"
   1: "text1"
   2: "text2"
   3: "text3"
2: Array
   0: "2"
   1: "text1"
   2: "text2"
   3: "text3"
```

Comment: What did you try so far? Please share your code. Also Your sample Data and result doesn't look line array at all.

Comment: You want to map the user input to the index of inner arrays or to the values at oth position of each inner array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let arr = [ ["1","text1","text2","text3"],["2","text1","text2","text3"],["3","text1","text2","text3"]]
const newOrder = [3,2,1];

let result = newOrder.map(idx => arr.find(el => el[0] == idx))

console.log(result)
```

Comment: I'm sorry. I tried the code and it works. But Jquery in project is not use "=>" How do I fix it?

Comment: let result = newOrder.map(function(idx){return arr.find(function(el){return el[0] == idx})})

Answer (score 2):

```js
    let yourObj = {0:{ 
       0: "1",
       1: "text1",
       2: "text2",
       3: "text3"},
    1: {
       0: "2",
       1: "text1",
       2: "text2",
       3: "text3"},
    2: {
       0: "3",
       1: "text1",
       2: "text2",
       3: "text3"}
    },
    input = [3,2,1];

    let sortArr = (input) => {
    
    let obj = {};
    
    for(let i = 0; i< input.length; i++){
    obj[i] = yourObj[--input[i]];
    
    }
    return obj;
    }

     console.log(sortArr(input))   //Call sort array here
```